# why number of set bits is needed?

Tags: bit-manipulation

i found a problem in codeforces 579/A:

> You are a lover of bacteria. You want to raise some bacteria in a box.
>
> Initially, the box is empty. Each morning, you can put any number of
>   bacteria into the box. And each night, every bacterium in the box will
>   split into two bacteria. You hope to see exactly x bacteria in the box
>   at some moment.
>
> What is the minimum number of bacteria you need to put into the box
>   across those days?
>
> Input The only line containing one integer x (1 ≤ x ≤ 109).
>
> Output The only line containing one integer: the answer.
>
> input : 5 output: 2 Note: For the first sample, we can add one
>   bacterium in the box in the first day morning and at the third morning
>   there will be 4 bacteria in the box. Now we put one more resulting 5
>   in the box. We added 2 bacteria in the process so the answer is 2.

My ques is, why number of set bit is used here to solve this?

Comment: Well, how else would you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Each time you inject 1 bacteria, the number of germs will be 2<sup>n</sup> after *n* days. In order to reach a number N, you have to see its powers of 2.

> 5 is 2<sup>2</sup> +  2<sup>0</sup> or 4 + 1.

that is, in binary, 5 is `101`, which is your injection planning!

To reach 5,

- (1) add 1 bacteria
- (0) after a day add 0 bacteria and
- (1) after another day add 1 bacteria

The maximum acceptable number is `109` or `1101101` in binary. To reach 109, add 1 , then 1 after a day, then 0, then 1...

From the left,

- the first 1 will give 2<sup>6</sup> after 6 days (64)
- the second 1 will give 2<sup>5</sup> after 5 days (32)
- the third 1 will give 2<sup>3</sup> after 3 days (8)
- then... the 5 (4+1)

Finally, to know how many bacteria you'll have to inject, just count the number of `1` in the target binary number. That is, the number of bits set.

You may wonder why not injecting more than 1 at some day? Because the problem has no limitation on the number of days, so you'll "use" less bacteria by letting them multiply. That's the power of exponentiation!

Answer (score 1):

Any bacteria put on given day would become one, two, four, eight and so on bacterias. It will not become three, for example. It is always a power of two.
So, if desired number is not power of two, you need to make it as a sum of powers of two.
Minimum amount of addends in such sum is such that no power of two is repeated, each power is used 0 or 1 times. Representation of number as such sum of powers of two is basically converting it to binary representation, and counting used powers of two is counting binary digits set to one.